# Replacing in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace

So i have a scenario where i have strings like:

```
TERMS of use    [ER]
SERVICE manager ER Data
Stack OVERFLOW  (ER) check
ERPS Value         ER
GDPER   checks ER
```

These are the strings where you can see space , multi space or tab between the strings.
i want to replace 'ER' with 'GD'.

So i used on command prompt:

```
perl -n -e 's/[[,(]?ER[),]]?/GD/g&&print';
```

Input: `GDPER checks ER`

Output: `GDPGD checks GD`

Required: `GDPER checks GD'`

Comment: Have you looked at the "word boundary" `\b` zero-width assertion in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) ? It does just what you need. If you show the relevant code (+ test data) you have as an [mcve], you are more likely to get good answers.

Comment: Try running : perl -n -e 's/[\[,\(]?ER[\),\]]?/GD/g&&print' on your command prompt and provide 'GDPER   checks ER' as input . you will get 'GDPGD   checks GD' as output. Where as I expect it to be 'GDPER   checks GD'

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the relevant code and data and explanation there, instead of posting this in the comments.

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: The question marks say "this could be here or not here". It's generally not useful to put in a boundary condition which is optional because then you are permitting no boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

**NOTE:** `\K` requires Perl >= 5.10.0.

```perl
$ perl -pe 's/(?:\b|[[:upper:]]*[[:lower:]]+\w*\K)ER\b/GD/g'
```

Input (copy & paste)

```
TERMS of use    [ER]
SERVICE manager ER Data
Stack OVERFLOW  (ER) check
ERPS Value         ER
GDPER   checks ER
ThisTestCaseDoesNotReplaceER
```

Output

```
TERMS of use    [GD]
SERVICE manager GD Data
Stack OVERFLOW  (GD) check
ERPS Value         GD
GDPER   checks GD
ThisTestCaseDoesNotReplaceGD
```

Comment: This just works fine ! 
but a case is there 'ThisTestCaseDoesNotReplaceER' string should replace and result should be 'ThisTestCaseDoesNotReplaceGD'

Comment: That will be difficult, because you do not want to replace it in `GPDER checks ER`, i.e. the simple approach `s/\b?ER\b/GD/g` won't work. So what is the differentiating factor between `GPDER ` and `ThisTestCaseDoesNotReplaceER `?

Comment: Camel case is the only thing that i get in such type of strings

Comment: Updated to handle the camel case mentioned by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Another Perl using positive lookbehind

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=\[|\s|\()ER/GD/g' kanishka.txt
TERMS of use    [GD]
SERVICE manager GD Data
Stack OVERFLOW  (GD) check
ERPS Value         GD
GDPER   checks GD

$
```

with one more edge case as mentioned by OP in the comments

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=\[|\s|\(|[a-z])ER/GD/g' kanishka.txt2
TERMS of use    [GD]
SERVICE manager GD Data
Stack OVERFLOW  (GD) check
ERPS Value         GD
GDPER   checks GD
ThisTestCaseDoesNotReplaceGD


$ cat kanishka.txt2
TERMS of use    [ER]
SERVICE manager ER Data
Stack OVERFLOW  (ER) check
ERPS Value         ER
GDPER   checks ER
ThisTestCaseDoesNotReplaceER


$
```